# LINUX : mail send file content as mail content

Tags: linux, email

I created a `.sh` script, and logging result in a file, after execution i would try to send the file content as `mail` body.

This is the command I run :

```
sh update.sh >> update.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H").txt 2>&1 && mail -s "Integration : import du $(date +%Y-%m-%d) a $(date +%H)h" sample@example.com < update.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H").txt
```

Is that good ?

Here is the code of `update.sh` :

```sh
#!/bin/ksh
. /root/.bash_profile

red='\033[0;31m'
green='\033[0;32m'
yellow='\033[1;33m'
blue='\033[0;34m'
purple='\033[0;35m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
DATE=$(date +%d-%m-%Y\ %H:%M:%S)
quiet=
composer=

echo " "
echo -e "  ${green}[${DATE}]${purple}  Mise a jour de dalia${NC}"
echo " "

function update_composer {
    if [ "$composer" == 1 ]; then
        echo " "
        echo -e "  ${yellow}Mise a jour de composer (des vendors)${NC}"
        if [ "$quiet" == 1 ]; then
            composer update --prefer-dist -q
        else
            composer update --prefer-dist
        fi
        echo " "
    fi
}

function update_db {
    echo " "
    echo -e "  ${yellow}Mise a jour de la base de donnee${NC}"
    if [ "$quiet" == 1 ]; then
        php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force -q
    else
        php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
    fi
    echo " "
}

function update_svn {
    echo " "
    echo -e "  ${yellow}Mise a jour depuis svn${NC}"
    if [ "$quiet" == 1 ]; then
        svn update -q
    else
        svn update
    fi
    echo " "
}

function install_assets {
    echo " "
    echo -e "  ${yellow}Installation des assets${NC}"
    if [ "$quiet" == 1 ]; then
        php app/console assets:install --env=prod -q && php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod -q
    else
        php app/console assets:install --env=prod && php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
    fi
    echo " "
}

function cache_clear {
    echo " "
    echo -e "  ${yellow}Effacement du cache de prod${NC}"
    if [ "$quiet" == 1 ]; then
        php app/console cache:clear --env=prod -q
    else
        php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
    fi
    echo " "
}

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -q | --quiet )          quiet=1
;;
-c | --composer )       composer=1
;;
esac
shift
done

while [ "$2" != "" ]; do
    case $2 in
        -q | --quiet )          quiet=1
;;
-c | --composer )       composer=1
;;
esac
shift
done

update_svn
update_composer
update_db
cache_clear
install_assets
cache_clear

echo " "
echo -e "  ${blue}Changement des permissions${NC}"
chmod 777 -R * && chown apache:apache -R *
echo " "

echo -e "  ${green}Fait${NC}"

echo " "
```

Comment: can you just show me the code of your script ?

Comment: Terminal color codes don't work in email as such.

Comment: that's why i'm receiving the log content as a `.dat` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Terminal color codes don't work in email as such

That's it, I removed all colors and replaced all `echo -e` by `echo` and the mail content was good.